# Understand Picard-Lindelöf Proof

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to understand the Picard-Lindelöf from my book which uses the fixed point theorem.
The task is trying to find $x \in C(a,b)$ in open interval $(a, b)$ containing $t_0$ such that it satisfies the integral equation $x(t) = x_0 + \int_{t_0}^{t}f(s, x(s))ds$ for all $t \in (a, b).$

Here $C(a,b)$ denotes the set of bounded continuous functions and for $a < t_0 < b$ and $\beta > 0$ define $K = [a, b] \times \overline{B(x_0, \beta)}$

Define $X \subset C(a,b)$ be set of continuous functions $x: (a,b) \rightarrow R^n$ such that $\|x(t)-x_0\| \leq \beta$ for $t \in (a,b).$ 
The task is to show that X is complete so for a Cauchy sequence $\{x_k\} \in X$ since $C[a, b]$ is complete, it converges to a function $x \in C(a,b)$ and the goal remains to show that $x \in X$.

Then $\|x(t)-x_0\| = lim_{p \rightarrow \infty}\|x_p(t)-x_0\| \leq \beta$ for $t \in (a,b)$ since $\|x_{p}(t) - x_0\| \leq \beta$ for $t \in (a,b).$ Thus this shows that $x \in X$. I understand everything up to this point.

What I don't understand is the next part:

Moreover there is no loss of generality in looking for fixed points in X and not in C(a,b). Indeed if $x: (a,b) \rightarrow R^n$ is continuous and satisfies the integral equation, then $\|x(t)-x_0\| \leq \|\int_{t_0}^{t}f(s,x(s))ds\| \leq|t-t_0|M \leq (b-a)M$ where $M = max\{\|f(t,x)\|: (t,x) \in K\} < \infty$ because f is continuous and K is compact. This shows that if $x \in C(a,b)$ then it belongs to X for some $\beta$.

What I don't understand is why the second argument is necessary. Didn't the first argument already show that if $x(t) \in C(a,b) \implies x(t) \in X$?

Comment: The first part showed that if $x \in C(a,b)$ is a limit of functions in $X$, then $x$ itself is in $X$. Not that all $y \in C(a,b)$ are in $X$.

Comment: No, the point of $X$ is to have a family of functions with range contained in a closed ball around $x_0$ with finite radius. $C(a,b)$ is a vector space and contains functions whose range can be arbitrarily large, and lies far away from $x_0$.

Comment: There seems to be some circularity in their argument. In obtaining the bound on $\|x(t)-x_0\|$, they are presuming that they have found a fixed point already (or maybe there is a transcription error?). To apply the bound they have above requires assuming that $\|x(t)-x_0\| \le \beta$ in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

The big picture:

1. A certain subset $X\subset C[a,b]$ is introduced; we'll be looking for a solution of the integral equation in $X$.
2. $X$ is shown to be closed in $C[a,b]$. Hence, $X$ is a complete metric space with the induced metric.
3. The restriction of the integral operator to $X$ is shown to be a contraction of $X$ into  $X$.
4. From 2 and 3 we conclude that the equation has a unique solution in $X$.
5. We rule out the possibility of solutions in $C[a,b]\setminus X$. This part is   needed for the uniqueness part of the theorem. (We already know there is exactly one solution in $X$, but what if there are solutions outside of $X$?)

Part 5 is what you are asking about.